# How do I prove the following inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

How do I proceed to solve the inequality 
 $$\frac{(a^2+b^2)}{(a+b)} + \frac {(b^2+c^2)}{(b+c)} + \frac{(a^2+c^2)}{(a+c)} \geq (a+b+c)$$  where $a , b , c > 0$
I have thought of taking the terms on the $LHS$ and converting them to $AM$ and then use the $AM-GM$ theorem , but I cant figure out how to convert $\frac {(a^2+b^2)}{(a+b)}$ to $AM$.
I have tried finding $a_1$ and $a_2$ by doing 
$ (\frac{(a_1+a_2)}{2}\bigr)^2 \geq$ $\frac{(a^2+b^2)}{(a+b)}$

Comment: Are the $a,b,c$ positive reals?

Comment: Yes , I am really sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$, $b$, $c>0$ then
$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}\ge\frac{a+b}2$$
etc.

Comment: Sir , how did you get that identity?Is that $AM-GM$ inequality?

Comment: I don't think so, but it's related to Cauchy-Schwarz. It's quite easy to prove from scratch.

Comment: @mampuuu This inequality is the quadratic-arithmetic mean inequality in disguise.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Cauchy Schwarz in Engel form](https://brilliant.org/wiki/titus-lemma/), we have

$$\!\!\frac{a^2}{a+b}+\frac{b^2}{b+c}+\frac{c^2}{a+c}+
\frac{b^2}{a+b}+\frac{c^2}{b+c}+\frac{a^2}{a+c}\geq \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{2(a+b+c)}+\frac{(b+c+a)^2}{2(a+b+c)}= a+b+c$$